# Access xml feed with HTAUTH in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, feed, password-protection

How can I access a xml feed with HAUTH in PHP?

Dummy link format is http://username:password@feeds.domain.net/www.domain.com/trends/001.xml

I'm using the code below to access it.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($source);
```

Thanks in advance,
steamboy

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use curl to get the content of the password protected file. Here is a class that enables you to easily get that data: http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php#90821

You need to set the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option in curl for the password protection.